# Finding $\int_{1/4}^4 \frac{1}{x}\sin(x-\frac{1}{x})\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

> Find the value of: $$\int_{1/4}^4 \frac{1}{x}\sin(x-\frac{1}{x})\,dx $$

**Attempt:**
I seriously have no idea how to attempt this question. I suppose I will first have to treat this as an indefinite integral to find the integration of the function, and then substitute the limits to find the value.
I tried to do this using the by-parts method, however to no avail. I can't think of what to substitute in order to solve the integral. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Wolfram suggests that there isn't an elementary antiderivative.
It might be worth considering an expansion of some sort of the sine term.

Comment: But the limits suggest something nice, maybe try put $x=\frac{1}{t}$

Comment: Indeed they do. That's a nice spot. (I was referring to the indefinite integral when I mentioned there not being an elementary antiderivative.)

Answer (score 13):

If we substitute $t=x-\frac{1}{x}$ (we are allowed since $g(x)=x-\frac{1}{x}$ is increasing and differentiable over $\left[\frac{1}{4},4\right]$), we are left with:
$$ I = \int_{-15/4}^{15/4}\sin(t)\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}$$
hence we are integrating an odd integrable function over a symmetric domain with respect to the origin, so the value of the integral is simply **zero**.

Comment: Upvoting your answer. Though the first thing which comes to most ordinary minds is the substitution 1/x = u, I really like your approach of being able to show that the function is odd and the domain is symmetric wrt the origin. Would like more people to appreciate your approach.

Answer (score 11):

if $I$ is your given integral, simply substitute $1/x = u$ and you will get $-I$, which means the value of the definite integral $I$ is zero.

Comment: Hmmm.. what property would that be?

Comment: IF I = -I , then I is obviously 0. Though i haven't verified if I indeed equal -I

Comment: @Gummy bears -- (1) sine is an odd function, (2) exchanging limits of integration reverses sign. Hope that helps

Comment: True, but only if you prove that the given function is integrable. Otherwise, the risk is to state something like $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}=0$$ that is not exactly true if $\int$ stands for the usual Riemann integral.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hmmm... but can't we find the definite integration of every function?

Comment: @Gummybears: definitely no. For instance, what should be $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\tan x}{\cos^2 x}\,dx $$ ?

Comment: Agreed. But between 1/4 and 4, there are no problem areas for the function, so, we can safely assume it is integrable. For the function you have stated, x = 0 is obviously going to be a problem area.

Comment: @Shailesh: also $\frac{1}{\color{red}{x}}\sin(x-1/x)$ has some issue in zero. We have to prove it is integrable.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio True, but look at the limits of integration - it does not contain zero, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Putting an end to this issue, the question was multiple choice xD. And yes @JackD'Aurizio I see the issue now. If the function is not defined at a certain point within the limits, we cannot find the integral of that function, correct?

Comment: @Shailesh: right for sure. I just think that it is worth to mention "the function is integrable since $\ldots$".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Once again, agreed, but I have written the solution itself in a line, so some assumptions were not laid out. Anyway, the issue ends. Thanks.